# Alarm Manager stops working periodically in Karbonn Android One Phone

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I'm using `Alarm Manager` to set alarm for next 5 min, which in turn will trigger a `broadcast receiver`.

Now when `receiver` is triggered, I set another alarm for next 5 min.
Which again triggers the `receiver`, and next alarm is set.

This process continues, until I manually stop it via button.

I need this process of `set/cancel` of `Alarm Manager` to continue working for a day, with a gap of 5 min, every time.

This works fine in my Moto G2 device, but in Karbonn Android One device, it has many gaps, where `Alarm` didn't trigger for hours.

Looks like device specific issue, but is there any way, this can be fixed?

I'm using below code to set alarm:

```
 AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    int uniqueRequestCode = (int)now.getTimeInMillis();

    alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
    alarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, uniqueRequestCode, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, now.getTimeInMillis(),
            alarmPendingIntent);
```

I also tried using `setRepeating()` method of `AlarmManager` here, but with that also, there were huge gaps in alarm trigger time. Thus tried this one, but no help.

This seems to work fine for first 1 hr, in Android One device, then starts causing issues.

*P.S
I'm also cancelling alarm, before setting a new one. And there's unique request code for every `pendingIntent` associated with alarm.

Comment: It might have something to do with battery saving settings. Some of them seem to suppress, or at least shift, alarms to not wake the device so often. Perhaps check those in the settings of the Karbonn device and compare them to the Moto G2's settings.

Comment: Can you please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34084253/alarmmanager-isnt-working/34084352#34084352 one ? Might be help you.

Comment: @Ridcully.....I checked for that, there's no batter saver mode ON, or any other such setting.

Comment: @Hiren....I'll check with this one....thanks